# Error in checkboxall in pageblocktable

Tags: pageblocktable

Iam trying to get checkbox all functionality in pageblocktable.

But Iam getting an error

> Invalid field selected for SObject ZIP__c

```
List<zipwrapper> zipList = new List<zipwrapper>();
    List<Zip__c> selectedZips = new List<Zip__C>();
public List<zipwrapper> getZips()
    {
        for(Zip__c z : [select Id, Name from Zip__c ])
        zipList.add(new zipwrapper(z));
        return zipList;
    }

public PageReference getSelected()
    {
        selectedZips.clear();
        for(zipwrapper zipwrapper : zipList)
        if(zipwrapper.selected == true)
        selectedZips.add(zipwrapper.zip);
        return null;
    }
     public List<ZIp__c> GetSelectedZips()
    {
        if(selectedZips.size()>0)
        return selectedZips;
        else
        return null;
    }    
    public class zipwrapper
    {
        public zip__c zip{get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}
        public zipwrapper(Zip__c z)
        {
            zip = z;
            selected = false;
        }
    }
```

What I am missing?

```
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!zipinfo}" var="zip" style="width:100%" id="ziptable">     
                                       <apex:column >

                                           <!-- <apex:facet name="header">
                                                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!allChecked}">
                                                    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!CheckAll}" rerender="ziptable"/>
                                                </apex:inputCheckbox>
                                            </apex:facet>-->
                                            <apex:facet name="header"> <apex:inputCheckbox >
                                            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!GetSelected}" onsubmit="checkAll(this)" rerender="ziptable"/>
                                            </apex:inputCheckbox></apex:facet>


                                           <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!zip.selected}" id="checkedone" />      
                                       </apex:column>                  
                                       <apex:column value="{!zip.name}" headerValue="Zip" />
                                       <apex:column value="{!zip.City__c}" headerValue="City" />
                                       <apex:column value="{!zip.State__c}" headerValue="State" />

                                   </apex:pageblockTable>
                                   </apex:outputPanel>                      
                                </apex:pageblock>
```

Comment: Could you post your VF page snippet containing the pageBlockTable too? Controller bit seems to be ok. Maybe in the pageBlockTable you are using list of SObjects rather than list of wrapper objects, basically resulting in a binding which tries to access a non-existant property of an SObject.

Comment: I added VF code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your VF code, you are obviously using Zip__c as an item in the table. If you take a look at last three columns of your simplified snippet:

```
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!zipinfo}" var="zip" style="width:100%" id="ziptable">     
   <apex:column >
       <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!zip.selected}" id="checkedone" />      
   </apex:column>                  
   <apex:column value="{!zip.name}" headerValue="Zip" />
   <apex:column value="{!zip.City__c}" headerValue="City" />
   <apex:column value="{!zip.State__c}" headerValue="State" />
</apex:pageblockTable>
```

..you will notice that you are accessing fields **name**, **City_*c*** and **State_c**, which are obviously fields of the Zip__*c* object, rather than of the **zipwrapper** object. 
In your controller, **zipinfo** is most probably List of Zip__c and not List of zipwrapper.

Update your VF page so that pageBlockTable uses *List of zipwrapper* and extend **zipwrapper** class to contain name/city/state fields.

Comment: The zipwrapper class is ok, IMO. Adding those individual fields to the wrapper class actually can serve to circumvent security...but he is missing them in his query which will cause the page to fail.